# Reusing an old Acer screen

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, raspberry-pi, lcd, control-system

I broke the motherboard of an old Acer notebook, and as a part of my fiddling, I managed to get the screen (+webcam) off the rest of the body.

It looks like this :

[image]

Now, I have two cables going out on the right side (photo 1), and on the left one cable (photo 2) + many very very small ones in a sheath (photo 3) :

[image]

[image]
[image]

**Is there any way I can use it without dismounting it completely and using an LVDS controller ?**

Comment: The small coax (white) one is almost surely the WiFi antenna.

Comment: Both black and white cables with the gold (plated) connectors are for the WiFi antennas. *using an LVDS controller* If you are able to connect all those small wires properly to the LVDS controler and are able to make the backlight work (probably easiest) then yes you can. In practice it will be a **huge** challenge to properly connect the signals and make that work. I think you can only do it if you have the proper connector and make a custom PCB to connect to the controller. I'd say: not worth the trouble.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. You've ripped the display connector off of the cable (in the third picture), destroying it.